# Interactig music, pictures fies from ubuntu to window

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, files

I'm new to Linux in general. I decided to dual-boot today. I know people have said to never interact with anything on Windows from a Linux system. But what about music and picture files? How much damage could I do if I were to say play the music on Ubuntu. Or copy the files to Ubuntu.

Comment: @24601 This is not a duplicate. OP wants to share files in the **same computer** from Windows to Ubuntu while dual booting. Samba is used for sharing between two computers. Samba can't be used in dual booting, when Windows is not running.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a shared data only partition - must use a file system understood by both OSes, that means typically NTFS - but you should avoid accessing the Windows **system** partition (typically C:\) from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux supports the ntfs file system of MS Windows. You therefore can access, and even work, with data on a Windows partition.

There is, of course, an additional risk if you have Linux read and write on a Windows system partition. Allegedly, drivers for ntfs in Linux are around for many years, and of solid quality. The risk therefore can be considered small. Still, it is preferred if data could be on a separate third partition, formatted in ntfs so it can be shared between Windows and Linux.

When sharing partitions between Windows and Linux, there are a few precautions you should take.

- "Fast start" in Windows needs to be disabled. As one of the tricks to shorten startup times, Windows does not properly close partitions it used. Linux will not mount a partition for writing if the file system is not clean.
- Windows needs to be fully shut down before moving to Linux. The reason is the same: when hibernating, Windows will not close the file systems that are in use.